# Python: print list of list in a specified format

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list of list `l = [['a','b', 'c'], 'd','e', ['f', 'g']]`. It is not always necessary that list elements are going to be alphabets.

Now, I used the below code:

```
>>> index =1
>>> for i in l:
...     if isinstance(i, list):
...             for j in i :
...                     print index, j
...                     index = index + 1
...     else:
...             print index, i
...             index = index + 1
... 
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
6 f
7 g
```

You can see the format in which I have printed out the result.

Another example:

```
l = [['aaa','bbb','xxx'], 'ddd']

Output = 

1 aaa
2 bbb
3 xxx
4 ddd
```

My question is there any better way to do this or any `built-in` function in python.

PS: Lists will be only 1 level nested. So, `[ [a, [b,c] ], d, e ]` is not a possibility.

Comment: One thing that is worth asking is whether you really want to hold data in this fashion.  In other words, how do you get a list which contains lists and strings in the first place?  Generally, it's easier if you can unify things so that your list holds only 1 data-type.

Comment: @mgilson: Let me give an example suppose I have a list of words `['w1', 'w2', 'w3']` and now I created a function `get_meanings(word)` which will return the meanings of the word passed as an argument. Than I used `map(get_meanings, words)` which will return me the o/p of the above form because if  a word have more than one meaning available the api returns a `list`.

Comment: @ronnie The best solution there is to have the function return lists of length one for one result. It makes it easier to work with when you get the result.

Comment: @Lattyware: Can you please explain it in a  more detailed form.

Comment: @ronnie So, at the moment, you have ``get_meanings(word)`` returning ``["meaning1", "meaning2"]`` where there are multiple meanings or ``"meaning"`` where there is one - my suggestion is make it return ``["meaning"]`` in the second case, removing a need for special treatment when you process it.

Comment: @Lattyware: that can be done thanks.

Comment: @Lattyware -- Thanks for taking over explaining the data-structures here.  Nice work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this very easily with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [['a','b', 'c'], 'd','e', ['f', 'g']]
>>> for index, value in enumerate(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l), 1):
...     print(index, value)
... 
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
6 f
7 g
```

Edit: As mgilson pointed out, this doesn't work well with multi-character strings as elements at the top level. I would argue the best solution then is to use a generator as he does in his answer, however, I would argue that the string is the special case, not the list, so I would reverse the logic:

```
def flatten(seq):
    for item in seq:
        if not isinstance(item, str): #Use `basestring` in 2.x
            yield from item
            #For Python <3.3
            #for subitem in item:
            #    yield subitem
        else:
            yield item
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work for a list of the form:  `l = [['aa','b', 'c'], 'dd','e', ['ff', 'g']]`  (the `dd` in the middle gets split into 2 elements).

Comment: @mgilson That is very true, didn't think of that one.

Comment: And in py2k, you'll probably want to use `isinstance(item,basestring)` to catch unicode strings as well.

Comment: @mgilson Another good point. I don't use 2.x enough to think of that one. Cheers for all the catches.

Comment: no problem.  Happy to make SO a better place :).  And nice answer by the way.  I particularly like python 3.3's `yield from iterable` syntax.  That's neat.

Comment: @mgilson It makes these kind of iterators infinitely nicer too look at.

Comment: @Lattyware: Thanks your solution to return a single element list instead of string worked nicley. Now my code is looking much more cleaner/elegant.

Answer (score 6):

I would create a generator to flatten the list:

```
def flatten(lst):
   for i in lst:
       if(isinstance(i,list)):
          for x in i:
              yield x
       else:
           yield x
```

Then I would use `enumerate` for the printing:

```
for idx,item in enumerate(flatten(lst),1):
    print idx,item
```

Comment: Nice, I was not aware of `generator` in python.

Comment: I would do this if there was variable nesting. This seems to be a little overkill for a max of one level of nesting

Comment: @mgilson: I meant the concept of flattening before printing

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I completely disagree, doing it this way makes the code infinitely more readable and clear.

Comment: @Lattyware: for a <=1 level nested list, chaining is so much simpler. If nesting level was <=n, n>1, then flattening is not only required, but makes it more readable too. As long as the programmer knows what chaining is, I'd say chaining is more readable. But perhaps that's a subjective thing

Comment: @inspectorG4dget -- the problem with "chaining" is that strings are iterables.  So if you have a string like "foobar" at the toplevel, when you "chain" that, you end up with `...,'f','o','o','b','a','r',...`.  Otherwise, I agree that chaining is the way to go here.  I suppose you could do `for x in it.chain(*([x] if isinstance(x,basestring) else x for x in lst)):`, but that's starting to get pretty hard to read in my opinion ...

Comment: @mgilson: fair enough. That is definitely an argument that I can get behind